# search for the best solution to make it ( select * from table order by rand() limit 40 ) run faster

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select * from table order by rand() limit 40
```

As we know, this works as expected,but it takes too long time.
so i need to make it run faster.

I get some solutions,like this:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM talbe AS t1 JOIN
    (SELECT ROUND(RAND() * ((SELECT MAX(id) FROM table)-(SELECT MIN(id) FROM table))+(SELECT MIN(id) FROM table)) AS id) AS t2 
WHERE t1.id >= t2.id AND t1.type=1 
ORDER BY t1.id 
LIMIT 40
```

but it doesn't work exactly.
sometimes it can't get 40 rows records.

Comment: Found this article, maybe it can help? http://explainextended.com/2009/03/01/selecting-random-rows/

Comment: Do you need 40 random records, or 40 records starting from a random point? Your 2nd solution above is finding a random record and then taking 40 records from that id onwards (which of course will not work when the randomly selected record happens to have the highest id)

Comment: @eggyal I really can't understand the second sentence. I copy it from the web ,thanks for your commentate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you understand what your second version is doing?

It is selecting up to 40 records with `id` greater than or equal to a random number between `MIN(id)` and `MAX(id)`. In a sense, this *isn't* selecting 40 random records: it's selecting *one* random record and the 39 that follow by `id`. One could say it's selecting a random cluster of records.  Obviously, if the randomly selected record is too close to the maximum `id` there will not be 39 that follow.

Furthermore, the probability of each cluster is distributed with `id`—so any lack of uniformity in that column (e.g. gaps where records have been deleted) leads to a lack of uniformity in the results.  In extremis, imagine one has the eighty records with `id` 1–40 and 1,000,001–1,000,040. The probability of any of the first forty being selected is a million times less than the last forty (since any random value >40, e.g. 41 or 2,753 or 999,999 will return only records from 1,000,000 onwards).

So, if bearing all of that in mind, you are happy to continue using the second version despite its pitfalls then instead of the starting record being chosen by random `id` between `MIN(id)` and `MAX(id)` one could choose `id` between `MIN(id)` and the 40th `id` from the maximum.

```
SELECT   t1.*
FROM     `table` JOIN (
           SELECT min.id + ROUND(RAND() * (max.id - min.id)) AS id
           FROM   (SELECT id FROM `table` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 39, 1) max,
                  (SELECT id FROM `table` ORDER BY id ASC  LIMIT  0, 1) min
         ) AS pivot ON pivot.id <= table.id
WHERE    table.type = 1
ORDER BY table.id
LIMIT    40
```

However, if the above-mentioned pitfalls of this method are undesirable then [@Quassnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55159/quassnoi)'s article "[Selecting random rows](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/01/selecting-random-rows/)" (to which [@Kay Nelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/606294/kay-nelson) [linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015755/search-for-the-best-solution-to-make-it-select-from-table-order-by-rand-li#comment31588141_21015755)) provides a better solution based on comparing `RAND()` against the probability of the next record being selected.  I suggest adding a `LIMIT` clause to ensure that MySQL ceases its table scan once it has found the requisite number of random records:

```
SELECT  table.*, @lim := @lim - 1
FROM    `table`, (SELECT @cnt := COUNT(*) + 1, @lim := 40 FROM `table`) init
WHERE   RAND() < @lim / (@cnt := @cnt - 1)
LIMIT   40
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't quite understand what you said.But thank you very much, I'll take it！

Comment: @zhoumengkang: By all means if you'd like me to elaborate, do ask.  Not only will it help you to understand what's going on (rather than merely copying and praying) but if my answer can be made clearer then it is more likely to be of use to others in the future too.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL provides [HANDLER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/handler.html) which let us access directly storage engine.

With `HANDLER` we can open certain tblle and can navigate it back and forth. If you are considering random rows of one tblle, I think `HANDLER` is good choice for getting random rows with MySQL.

This approach is not ANSI standard and need to code more by your self, but you are considering performance matters, I think `HANDLER` is good for you.

### How to use

You can test here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddf01/4.

Assuming you are already know total record count of table and random numbers are generated by client side between 1 and `COUNT(*)`

In my example, table `tbl` has 20 records and I want to fetch random (6, 8, 10, 12, 15)th rows of table.

**basic usage**

```
-- OPEN tbl
HANDLER tbl OPEN;

-- READ 6th record
HANDLER tbl READ FIRST LIMIT 5, 1;

-- READ 8th record
HANDLER tbl READ FIRST LIMIT 7, 1;

-- READ 10th record
HANDLER tbl READ FIRST LIMIT 9, 1;

HANDLER tbl READ FIRST LIMIT 11, 1;
HANDLER tbl READ FIRST LIMIT 14, 1;

HANDLER tbl CLOSE;
```

preceding usage is easy to understand, but there are many disk seek (move 6th position and come back first and move 8th record, and so on) So, following code is much efficient.

```
-- OPEN tbl
HANDLER tbl OPEN;

-- READ 6th record
HANDLER tbl READ FIRST LIMIT 5, 1;

-- and READ 8th record
HANDLER tbl READ NEXT LIMIT 1, 1;

-- and READ 10th record
HANDLER tbl READ NEXT LIMIT 1, 1;

HANDLER tbl READ NEXT LIMIT 1, 1;
HANDLER tbl READ NEXT LIMIT 2, 1;

HANDLER tbl CLOSE;
```